# PHP - Can't access database-connector class from another class. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to accomplish the same ends as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017911/properly-using-classes-in-other-classes-in-php) but my application of that answer just does not work. I get blank white screens when attempting to perform any operation involving the database class.

This should be simple-- a user inputs a username and password into a form. If both are received by the controller, I query the database and compare a hash of the submitted password with the hash on file. The problem is, my page does not load once I start making database calls.

I have a controller and two classes. One class is a database connector, the other is an authentication module that depends on the database connector.

Database connector class:

```
class inquiry
{       
    protected $pdo;

    // Set up the initial db connection
    function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this -> pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mysqlserver','mydatabase','ffffffffffffffff');
            $this -> pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this -> pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
            $this -> pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this -> pdo -> exec('set names "utf8"');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e -> getMessage();
        } 
    }   
}
```

Then, the authentication class:

```
class auth
{
private $username;
private $password;
private $db;

function __construct(inquiry $db)
{
            $this -> db = $db;
}

function login($username, $password)
{
    $this -> username = $username;
    $this -> password = $password;

    // Query database, get hashed password for username
    $this -> db -> query('select password from users where username="bob";');

    // Data needs to be fetched but PHP does not process anything past this point anyway

    return true;
}
}
```

Then, in the controller:

```
require_once '../inc/class.inquiry.php';
require_once '../inc/class.auth.php';

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    // Probably doing something wrong here
    $dbconnect = new inquiry();
    $user = new auth($dbconnect);

    $authorized = $user -> login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    if ($authorized == true)
    {
        // Send user to index page
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

I've commented the sections where I *think* I'm going wrong, but I don't know what to actually do about it. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `inquiry` class does not have a method `query`!

Comment: Well damn! It sure doesn't. I don't necessarily want to write one though; I want to use the query function of the original PDO object. This gives me a good start though, thanks!

Comment: You could use magic methods to pass any unknown method calls to `$this->pdo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your code is wrong on  many levels. Starting from code standards where class should start with uppercase letter, formatting the code, finishing to calling a non-existent method.

First of all, your `inquiry` class does not have the desired `query()` method. It seems you try to give us a code you have not written by yourself, to debug.

Second, your class is completely USELESS. Even though it does not have a custom wrapping query method, you still could use PDO's method for querying and execute a query. However, even you are assigning value of object of type PDO to your `protected $pdo` you have absolutely NO ACCESS to this `$pdo` outside the class i.e. from `auth` class. You should write an accessor for `$pdo`, so you can use something like

```
$this->db->getPdo()->prepare("SELECT ......");
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did write the code, as this is an exercise in learning OOP, which is why it's so bad :)

Comment: @ivan you should turn on the error reporting as well, because if blank page, you should have recieved `Call to undefined method query()`

Comment: Ugh, thanks. I have the debug options enabled as an include, but they were commented out. I was wondering why this project was giving me so much trouble.